# LINQ OrderBy help needed

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

I'm trying to create a collection of strings in an order defined by another array. Sounds confusing I know so let me explain

**requiredOrderOfElements**

```
{  
[0] category1,  
[1] categoryX,  
[2] something else  
}
```

my client passes up a string array containing the key and value ie

**passed from client**

```
{  
[0][0] categoryX,  
[0][1] value from Category X,  
[1][0] something else,  
[1][1] value for something else,  
[2][0] category1,  
[2][1] value from Category 1  
}
```

what I want, is the "value" texts in the required order of the keys

**what I want**

```
[0]value from Category 1  
[1]value from Category X  
[2]value for something else
```

I've looked at OrderBy / IComparer and can't see an obvious way to implement what I need. My current solution is an ugly nested for-loop

Any ideas for a more elegant way would be appreciated.

Update: - here is the test

```
[TestFixture]
public class GL_Linq_Test
{
    [Test]
    public void CanOrderByAnotherArray()
    {
        var requiredOrder=new[]{"my","required","order"};
        var passedFromClient = new[]
                                   {
                                       new[] {"required", "cat"},
                                       new[] {"order", "dog"},
                                       new[] {"my", "bird"}
                                   };

        var ordered = FunkyOrderer.Order(requiredOrder, passedFromClient);

        Assert.That(ordered.First()[1],Is.EqualTo("bird"));
        Assert.That(ordered.Skip(1).First()[1], Is.EqualTo("cat"));
        Assert.That(ordered.Skip(2).First()[1], Is.EqualTo("dog"));
    }
}

public static class FunkyOrderer
{
//returns order bird,dog,cat not bird,cat,dog        
public static IEnumerable<string[]> Order(string[] requiredOrder, IEnumerable<string[]>passedFromClient)
    {
        return from o in requiredOrder
                     join f in passedFromClient on o equals f[0]
                     orderby o
                     select f;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Gilly - This is hardly enough information to even begin to make sense. Please post some sample code or a layout of how each array actually looks.

Comment: Hmmmm, not sure what else to put in! I'll post a test below and see if that explains it any better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you assuming an array of strings will be ordered by their index (they won't). The order of `"my", "order", "required"` is correct using the built in string comparer. The easiest solution is to modify your LINQ query to take the index into account when ordering.

```
return from o in requiredOrder.Select((o, i) => new { Value = o, Index = i })
       join f in passedFromClient on o.Value equals f[0]
       orderby o.Index
       select f;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var orderByThese = new string[] { "category1", "categoryX", "something else" };

    var fromClient = new string[][] 
    {
        new string[] { "categoryX", "value from Category X" },
        new string[] { "something else", "value for something else" },
        new string[] { "category1", "value from Category 1" }
    };

    var joined = from o in orderByThese
                 join f in fromClient on o equals f[0]
                 orderby o
                 select f;
```

Comment: not quite - gets the first item in the array correctly but the other two are the wrong way around. I'll post a test